# List button with JavaScript to open a window

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a List button with the following JavaScript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}
if({!Account.Credit_Status__c}='REJECTED') {
window.alert ("New Opportunity cannot be created when Account Credit Status = Rejected");
}
else {
window.open('/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&opp11=Prospecting');
}
```

This works when the Account status = Rejected, but when the status is not. I get this error message "Expected )"  I have tried different things to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking with `double = (==)`.

For example:

```
if({!Account.Credit_Status__c}=='REJECTED') { ...
```